# Fourier Transforms of functions on a finite interval

Tags: fourier-transform

I would like to find the fourier transform of $\sin(ax)$ which is non zero only on $-c\le x \le c$.

Calculating, I get an answer with sines and cosines but I'm not sure if this is correct... Should I be using the delta function in my answer? Or is that if the interval is infinite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can represent your function as
$$
f(x)=[\theta(x+c)-\theta(x-c)]\sin(ax)
$$
being $\theta(x)$ the [Heaviside step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function). Then, the Fourier integral becomes rather easy as
$$
{\cal F}(f)(k)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx e^{ikx}f(x)=\int_{-c}^c dx e^{ikx}\sin(ax). 
$$
The latter integral is very well-known and rather easy to evaluate.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I get an integral involving sin(ac) and cos(kc),does this sound correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!

Comment: If you like the answer, please accept it.